# Using ADAL JS Lib in JS App

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api

I need to use the ADAL JS lib for my office 365 add-in. I went through the github page [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). I saw the example is given in the form of an Angular JS App. Is there any example which can be used in plain JS app. The office add-in was created from Napa Dev tools which generates a basic skeleton and I am building the app on top of it. Do you think Angular JS would be a better option to build the outlook office add-in?

I plan to use the [Outlook 365 REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations) in the app, before doing that I need the authentication module to be working. I need to get the token so that I can pass on to the endpoint in order to execute the REST APIs.

Please correct me if my approach seems to be in the wrong direction and also let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL JS was definitely built with SPAs in mind, which is why it was made with an Angular module. You really have 2 options here, depending on how comfortable with Angular you are.

1. Build out your Add-in as an Angular app. You'll be able to use ADAL JS as it's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/getting-started-Office-365-APIs?javascript).
2. Don't use Angular and don't use ADAL JS. It's just OAuth underneath, so you can use whatever you'd like to handle that. You can see an example on how to request an access token from Azure without Angular [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-CORS-to-access-files-in-Office-365).

Good luck!

Comment: If you find this helpful, please upvote it or mark it as the answer. And if you have other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey Joe, I have another question, if I create an Angular app and want to package it as an Office Add-in how would I do it? I want my app to be displayed in the Office 365 Outlook when the user opens any email. Do you think it is a valid approach? Or Should I be hosting the Angular app on a web server and provide the user with the web link. The user will put the weblink into there Azure settings and will be able to access the app on the outlook window?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve in the app is that I want to use both the JavaScript API [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx) and the Outlook Mail Rest APIs. Javascript API gives me the itemId for the current email which is loaded and with that I can make REST API calls to do mailbox manipulation.